# Booting into safe graphics mode after Nvidia driver upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I decided to upgrade the nvidia driver I was using, I opened additional drivers and previously it was 660(proprietary), it had a new version 670(proprietary, tested). It also has tested in it, so I thought what could go wrong. I selected the driver and clicked apply. It downloaded the driver and told me to restart. I restarted and now I'm booting into what seems to be safe graphics mode, I'm unable to use my touchpad, Bluetooth and anything and there are no animations. I tried to revert back to 660 driver, but I can't use either WiFi or Ethernet.

I have secure boot enabled.

Comment: So disable Secure Boot and try again (or use mokutil to sign and trust the proprietary drivers) otherwise no matter what version you installed it won't work, Secure Boot prevents unsigned drivers from loading. By the way, the versions are 460 and 470 respectively.

Comment: I tried disabling Secret Boot, but it won't boot the proprietary drivers. I looked for the option in my bios to sign and trust the proprietary drivers, but I couldn't find it. I guess disabling secure boot and reinstallation is the only way.

Comment: The option to sign the drivers is at the OS, not the firmware.

Comment: I looked up mokutil, it's a bit complex for me. I think a better choice would be to just disable Secure Boot and reinstall because I may run into similar problems in the future by updating drivers and upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version.